# merge data.table when the number of key columns are different

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am attempting to understand the logic in the `data.table` from the documentation and a bit unclear.  I know I can just try this and see what happens but I would like to make sure that there is no pathological case and therefore would like to know how the logic was actually coded. When two `data.table` objects have a different number of key columns, for example `a` has 2 and `b` has 3, and you run `c <- a[b]`, will `a` and `b` be merged simply on the first two key columns or will the third column in a be automatically merged to the 3rd key column in `b`?  An example:

```
require(data.table)
a <- data.table(id=1:10, t=1:20, v=1:40, key=c("id", "t"))
b <- data.table(id=1:10, v2=1:20, key="id")
c <- a[b]
```

This should select rows of `a` that match the `id` key column in `b`. For example, for `id==1` in `b`, there are 2 rows in `b` and 4 rows in `a` that should generate 8 rows in `c`. This is indeed what seems to happen:

```
> head(c,10)
    id  t  v v2
 1:  1  1  1  1
 2:  1  1 21  1
 3:  1 11 11  1
 4:  1 11 31  1
 5:  1  1  1 11
 6:  1  1 21 11
 7:  1 11 11 11
 8:  1 11 31 11
 9:  2  2  2  2
10:  2  2 22  2
```

The other way to try it is to do:

```
d <-b[a]
```

This should do the same thing: for every row in `a` it should select the matching row in `b`: since `a` has an extra key column, `t`, that column should not be used for matching and a join based only on the first key column, `id` should be done.  It seems like this is the case:

```
> head(d,10)
    id v2  t  v
 1:  1  1  1  1
 2:  1 11  1  1
 3:  1  1  1 21
 4:  1 11  1 21
 5:  1  1 11 11
 6:  1 11 11 11
 7:  1  1 11 31
 8:  1 11 11 31
 9:  2  2  2  2
10:  2 12  2  2
```

Can someone confirm? To be clear: is the third key column of `a` ever used in any of the merges or does `data.table` only use the `min(length(key(DT)))` of the two tables.

Comment: If you showed what you tried and what you think is going on, and then just asked for confirmation that what you're inferring is in fact how it works, I'd be a lot more excited about this question.

Comment: @GSee: done, do you think is outlines what I'm trying to understand ok?

Comment: So your question is: does this output match what you described? I'd say yes.  The merges are happening exactly as you describe.  The sorting order is different both rows and columns because of the different columns in `a` and `b` and due to the way recycling works. i.e. the difference between `rep(1:10, 10)` and `rep(1:10, each=10)`

Comment: As I read it, it says, "if there is more than one key, is only the first used?"

Comment: @GSee, yes, that is exactly the question: does the third key get matched to the third column or is it not used if the other table has only 2 keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. First the correct terminology is (from `?data.table`) :

> [A data.table] may have *one key* of one or more *columns*. This key can be used for row indexing instead of rownames.

So "key" (singlular) not "keys" (plural). We can get away with "keys", currently. But when secondary keys are added in future, there may *then* be multiple keys.  Each *key* (singular) can have multiple *columns* (plural).

Otherwise you're absolutely correct. The following paragraph was improved in v1.8.2 based on feedback from others also confused. From `?data.table`:

> When i is a data.table, x must have a key. i is joined to x using x's key and the rows in x that match are returned. An equi-join is performed between each column in i to each column in x's key; i.e., column 1 of i is matched to the 1st column of x's key, column 2 to the second, etc. The match is a binary search in compiled C in O(log n) time. If i has fewer columns than x's key then many rows of x will ordinarily match to each row of i since not all of x's key columns will be joined to (a common use case). If i has more columns than x's key, the columns of i not involved in the join are included in the result. If i also has a key, it is i's key columns that are used to match to x's key columns (column 1 of i's key is joined to column 1 of x's key, column 2 to column 2, and so on) and a binary merge of the two tables is carried out. In all joins the names of the columns are irrelevant. The columns of x's key are joined to in order, either from column 1 onwards of i when i is unkeyed, or from column 1 onwards of i's key.

---

Following comments, in v1.8.3 (on R-Forge) this now reads (changes in bold) :

> When i is a data.table, x must have a key. i is joined to x using x's key and the rows in x that match are returned. An equi-join is performed between each column in i to each column in x's key; i.e., column 1 of i is matched to the 1st column of x's key, column 2 to the second, etc. The match is a binary search in compiled C in O(log n) time. If i has fewer columns than x's key then not all of x's key columns will be joined to (a common use case) and many rows of x will (ordinarily) match to each row of i. If i has more columns than x's key, the columns of i not involved in the join are included in the result. If i also has a key, it is i's key columns that are used to match to x's key columns (column 1 of i's key is joined to column 1 of x's key, **column 2 of i's key to column 2 of x's key, and so on for as long as the shorter key**) and a binary merge of the two tables is carried out. In all joins the names of the columns are irrelevant; the columns of x's key are joined to in order, either from column 1 onwards of i when i is unkeyed, or from column 1 onwards of i's key. **In code, the number of join columns is determined by min(length(key(x)),if (haskey(i)) length(key(i)) else ncol(i)).**

Comment: This is the confusing part for me: "If i also has a key, it is i's key columns that are used to match to x's key columns (column 1 of i's key is joined to column 1 of x's key, column 2 to column 2, and so on)..." It makes it sound like we will use all the keys in `i` and match to columns in `x` even if we run out of columns in `x` that are part of the key. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: But if we run out key columns in x, then what else could we do but stop there? Why does it make it sound like we will use all of i's key columns?

Comment: It sounds like scrolling through the columns of i that are the keys and then match to the 1st 2nd.. Nth column of x, even if only the first K<N are keyed.  Maybe I just read into it a bit more than I should have.

Comment: I can see that adding something like "when x and i are both keyed, there will be `min(length(key(i)),length(key(x)))` join columns; i.e., columns involved in the join". Would that help?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i was attempting to understand. i think it might help future users. now that you've clarified on SO, i think people will find this as well. thanks for the help.

Comment: In that part it says column 1 of i's key to column 1 of x's key, not column 1 of x, though.  Is it the "column 2 to column 2" bit? That's intended to mean "column 2 [of i's key] to column 2 [of x's key], and so on"

Comment: yeh that's exactly what threw me.

Comment: Ok, great. Will improve that. Thanks!

Comment: Changes committed and NEWS item added.

Answer (score 0):

Quote data.table [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf):

> X[Y] is a join, looking up X's rows using Y (or Y's key if it has one) as an index.
>   Y[X] is a join, looking up Y's rows using X (or X's key if it has one) as an index.
>   merge(X,Y) does both ways at the same time. The number of rows of X[Y] and Y[X] usually differ;
>   whereas the number of rows returned by merge(X,Y) and merge(Y,X) is the same.

Comment: apologies if the question was unclear but this is not related to what I was attempting to figure out.