# Matching value to more than one key column using join

Tags: r, join, data.table

Following in the spirit of this thread ([merge data.table when the number of key columns are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920803/merge-data-table-when-the-number-of-key-columns-are-different)), how would I match key columns in table A to a single value (from a table or not) where a matching row in A is when at least one column in A equals that value?

Here's a short example: let's say I have table A:

```
A <- data.table(b1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), b2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0), b3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), mis = FALSE)
setkey(A, b1, b2, b3)
```

Let's say the value I want to match in at least one column of A is 0. So the matching row in A would be rows 1, 2, and 5. I can get this result using this:

```
A[b1 == 0 | b2 == 0 | b3 == 0, ] # this is not so fast if A is large

    b1 b2 b3
1:  0  1  1
2:  1  1  0
3:  1  0  0
```

Is it possible to get the same result but using a faster join or merge operation?

I tried a few things, like this for example:

```
B <- data.table(v = 0)
A[B, ] # only matches with column b1 in A
```

Or this:

```
B <- data.table[b1 = 0, b2 = 0, b2 = 0]
setkey(B, b1, b2, b3)
A[B, ] # matches when all three corresponding columns match
```

Is it possible to come up with a formulation that will take advantage of the speed of binary search to achieve the result I'm looking for?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Arun: thanks for helping but it is slower than my first solution above AND it doesn't give the expected result. The result I'm looking for is a selection of the rows in A where ONE OR MORE columns (in b1, b2, b3) equal 0.

Comment: @Arun, no each column has values between 0 and 255

Comment: Real table A has about 58M rows, 4 columns

Comment: Running your code on the full table, A[rowSums(A == 0) > 0, mis := TRUE] runs in 13.53 s (elapsed time) versus 6.8 s for my code A[b1 == 0 | b2 == 0 | b3 == 0, mis := TRUE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick to get a little bit of an improvement is to use a join for the first comparison:

```
A[J(0), mis := TRUE]
A[b2 == 0 | b3 == 0, mis := TRUE]
```

Do note though that a simple comparison is always going to be faster than `setkey` + join - so resorting to a join only makes sense if you're doing it multiple times per `setkey` or if the key is already set for a different reason.

---

After thinking a bit - you *can* make this significantly faster by decreasing the number of operations involved (to 3 instead of the original 5). It's a little surprising that the following works, because it replaces the operations by presumably more expensive ones (at least naively I expect multiplication to be more expensive), but it *is* about 2x faster:

```
A[b1 * b2 * b3 == 0, mis := TRUE]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Actually I do not need the key for anything else. Is there an alternative to your suggestion but that doesn't need a key?

Comment: @Guilôme yes, it will only work if `b1` is the (first and/or only) key; if you don't need the key for anything else and you're only doing this once, then I don't think you can make it any faster than OP

Comment: @Guilôme actually see edit - you *can* make it faster

Comment: Good thinking! 3.45 s (total) on my full table! Super, many thanks! What if I'm looking for values == 255 instead of 0...

Comment: @Guilôme hmm, surprisingly `A[(255-b1)*(255-b2)*(255-b3) == 0]` is also faster than `A[b1 == 255 | b2 == 255 | b3 == 255]` - I have no clue why that would be the case :); this probably means my explanation of why it's faster for 0's is incorrect - maybe `|`'s are slower because R internally coerces integers to logicals?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your example is a general example and not the actual problem you're working on, so I took some liberties with the data -

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(
b1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 2), 
b2 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0), 
b3 = c(3, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)

Azerolist <- vector(mode = "list",length = ncol(A))

B1 <- data.table(
b11 = 0
)
setkeyv(A,c("b1"))
setkeyv(B1,c("b11"))
Azerolist[[1]] <- A[B1]
# b1 is zero, b2 or b3 might or might not be

B2 <- data.table(
b21 = 0,
b11 = 1
)
setkeyv(A,c("b2","b1"))
setkeyv(B2,c("b21","b11"))
Azerolist[[2]] <- A[B1, roll = Inf]
# b1 is not zero, b2 is zero, b3 might or might not be

B3 <- data.table(
b31 = 0,
b01 = 1
)
setkeyv(A,c("b3","b2"))
setkeyv(B3,c("b31","b01"))
A2 <- A[B1, roll = Inf]
setkeyv(A2,c("b3","b1"))
Azerolist[[3]] <- A2[B3, roll = Inf]
# b1 is not zero, b2 is not zero, b3 is zero

#ordering the columns in the same order for all data.tables in the list
Azerolist <- lapply(Azerolist, function(x) x[,colnames(A), with = FALSE])
# tada!
Azerodt <- rbindlist(Azerolist)
```

Comment: Like  I said, I assumed it's a generic example. The underlying question to ask is whether binary search can be used in such a fashion and that's what I'm trying to explore.

Comment: @Codoremifa: Thanks for helping. Let me know if you come up with something.

Comment: @Guilôme,how long does this method take on your dataset btw?

Comment: @Codoremifa, just one `setkey` operation alone takes more time than OP's method (on 58e6*4 data).

Comment: @Codoremifa: your method runs in 20.25 s (elapsed)

Comment: Well, that isn't helpful then. Thanks for chipping in on the experiment.

Comment: @Arun, Codoremifa method took 20.25 s (total time) on ~58M*6 data. Yours took 13.53 s.

Comment: @Arun, ok, let me know if you find something faster. Thanks!